# Chrome - open dev tools in new window

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

in chrome 43.0.2357.81 I can't find the little box which can separate devtools into a new window
I tried googling

> `q=open+inspect+element+in+new+window+chrome`

nothing new

Here is the Screen shot !
[image: Can't separate it in new windows]

Comment: I think that feature was disabled some months later. you can align the control panel vertically or horizontally by clicking the little icon near the 'x' at the top right

Comment: I need every pixel in the screen ... while developing apps for 7" or 10" tablets ... on my probook 1366x768 screen :( !

Comment: You can hold click on that icon and you get the answer :)

Comment: Lol man ^_^ that's the answer !!! Thx <3 <3 :*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can hold click on that icon and you get the answer :)**

answered by Ahmed :) !